помогите с написанием программы на Python по поводу input
помогите пожалуйста я пишу программу на питоне и мне нужно написать такой код:
A=input("Введите 0: [")

это будит выглядеть так:
Введите 0: [ответ пользователя

а мне нужно чтобы было так:
Введите 0: [ответ пользователя]

перед тем как пользователь введёт команду это должно быть так:
Введите 0: []

можно ли как нибудь это реализовать?

Чтобы пользователь писал внутри []?

A=input("Введите 0: [ответ пользователя]")?

А что должно происходить с закрывающей квадратной скобкой при вводе? Она должна отодвигаться вправо, верно я понимаю?

@u111 да имено так

@AlexeyTrukhanov да я хочу чтобы пользователь писал внутри скобок, а вторая скобка должна отодвигаться в вправо

print(f"Введите: {input()}") 


пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Это сообщение выведется только после того как пользователь что-то введет. Если я правильно понял автора - это не то, что ему нужно.

@AlexeyTrukhanov ты правильно понимаешь

Если Вы хотите сделать именно как консольное приложение , так сделать не получится в виду особенности самого input() и консоли.
Можно заморочиться: установить библиотеку keyboard , отслеживать каждое нажатие и под него менять внешний вид вводимой строчки , но стоит ли оно таких усилий?
